# How to use const createBrowserRouter at index file level: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router

I have the code structured in the following manner, When I try loading useBlocker, It throws the following error `Error: useBlocker must be used within a data router`. So inorder to fix this, we have to replace BrowserRouter with createBrowserRouter. How do I replace with the following structure.

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
    </ReduxProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Function app component

```
import {Routes, Route} from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./component/About";
import Team from "./component/Team";
import Home from "./component/Home";

function App() {
  return (
    <>
    <Navbar />
    <Routes >
      <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
      <Route path="/team" element={ <Team /> } />
      <Route path="/about" element={ <About /> } />
    </Routes>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How do we add `createBrowserRouter` in this case where I want to have my routes inside my App.tsx

EDIT 2:

withRouter hook

```
import {
  Location,
  NavigateFunction,
  Params,
  useLocation,
  useNavigate,
  useParams,
} from "react-router-dom";

export interface RouterProps {
  location: Location;
  navigate: NavigateFunction;
  params: Params;
}

export interface WithRouter {
  router: RouterProps;
}

function withRouter(Component: any) {
  function ComponentWithRouterProp(props: any) {
    const location = useLocation();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const params = useParams();
    return <Component {...props} router={{ location, navigate, params }} />;
  }

  return ComponentWithRouterProp;
}

export default withRouter;
```

```
class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
  constructor(props: IProps) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='container'>
        <Navbar />
        <Suspense>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={ <Home /> } />
          <Route path="/team" element={ <Team /> } />
          <Route path="/about" element={ <About /> } />
        </Routes>
        </Suspense>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Comment: Which part of using `createBrowserRouter` is unclear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't *need* to be declared in your index file, but it just needs to be declared/rendered higher in the ReactTree than any of the components that need to access the routing context it provides.

You can declare the router in the `App` file. Create a layout route to render the `Navbar`.

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from "react-redux";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ReduxProvider store={store}>
      <App />
    </ReduxProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

App.tsx

```
import {
  createBrowserRouter,
  createRoutesFromElements,
  RouterProvider,
  Route,
  Outlet,
} from "react-router-dom";
import About from "./component/About";
import Team from "./component/Team";
import Home from "./component/Home";

const AppLayout = () => (
  <>
    <Navbar />
    <Outlet />
  </>
);

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route element={<AppLayout />}>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/team" element={<Team />} />
      <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
    </Route>
  )
);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router} />;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: added an edit 2 in the question. index.tsx remains same.

Comment: @lrr59 FWIW it doesn't really matter if `App` is a Class or Function component since it just renders `RouterProvider`. `App` doesn't have any props and doesn't need the `withRouter` HOC.

Comment: the reason why I asked you was, it is giving me `useLocation() may be used only in the context of a <Router> component.`. this error is coming from withRouter hook

Comment: @lrr59 Ah yeah, you only need the `withRouter` HOC for the components rendered *under* the router that can't just use the `useLocation` hook directly. `App` ***can't*** use the `withRouter` HOC since it's the component rendering the router context, but the current `App` implementation doesn't need it anyway.

Comment: I have left the piece of using a prop inside App, somewhere I am accessing ` this.props.router.pathname` which I have not included in the snippet ( that uses withRouter). Any way we can achieve this? either fix `Error: useBlocker must be used within a data router` or use `createBrowserRouter ` inside a class based app component

Comment: @lrr59 I'm sure there is a way to address that. Do you mind creating a new post for this specific issue? Feel free to ping me here in another comment a link to the post and I can take a look when available.